# Modifier: Remeshing with blocks. What's the algorithm?

Tags: modifiers, geometry

In Blender there is a function representing your object with cubes (where you can find it: see attachment). This makes the object look like Minecraft style (see attachment).

This "Minecraft style" is the topic of my bachelor thesis. More precisely I have to create an algorithm that voxels an object. So there is an object represented with surface elements like triangles and this has to be represented with these blocks. This process is called preprocessing and is part of a FEM software.

Now I found this function in Blender and thought: "Wow, this is exactly what you have to do and WOW... this is fast."

Does anyone have an idea how this function/algorithm works? Maybe there is a part of the documentation I have overseen. I would be very happy if you could give me a helping hand. This remeshing algorithm in Blender would provide another approach to my own algorithm.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Function localization]

[image: Origin object]

[image: Object being remeshed]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using Blender

Comment: The beauty of open source software is that you have total access to its code base and can find out how everything works, or adapt and reuse it for your own purposes. You can just connect to the repositories, read the source code and learn from it.

Comment: There are a number of ways of doing voxelisation, including thenaive approach of just generating a grid and doing an inside/outside test on each cell. A quick google of voxelisation algorithm will find plenty of information.

Comment: If you need to dig more into algorithm details, https://cs.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better bet.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Well I am a newbie in this software business. I will read the source code.
Because I write my bachelor thesis about this you may think that I already googled this keyword. I also read 50 papers about this topic.
I just thought that additional information can be helpful for me, especially because the algorithm in blender is superfast.

Comment: After some time of searching, I found at least some code with matching keywords. [Here](https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/master/source/blender/modifiers/intern/MOD_remesh.c) you can find it. I do not know whether this helps because the are not any comments about what is happening in this part. Maybe here is an developer helping me or someone who can tell me how I can contact a developer.